# Joining 3 Tables, mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

How do i join all three tables? I have no idea, because i need to call them all into 1 table

customers

```
+--------+------------+---------------+---------+---------+
| serial |    name    |     email     | address |  phone  |
+--------+------------+---------------+---------+---------+
| 1      | first_name | email@web.com | address | 7777777 |
+--------+------------+---------------+---------+---------+
```

orders

```
+--------+------------+------------+
| serial |    date    | customerid |
+--------+------------+------------+
| 1      | 2014-03-04 | 1          |
+--------+------------+------------+
```

order_detail

```
+---------+-----------+----------+-------+
| orderid | productid | quantity | price |
+---------+-----------+----------+-------+
| 1       | 1         | 30       | 400   |
| 1       | 2         | 10       | 500   |
+---------+-----------+----------+-------+
```

`customerid` on table `orders` are the serial on table `customers` and `orderid` on table `order_detail` are the serial on `orders`

and what if i use another table? for the productid, where productid = product_id in another table?

help would be much appreciated, I am really sorry for the table, i have no idea how to make tables here but they are in order.

Comment: Have you looked into JOIN statements?

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to use Join statements. So you can do following

```
Select * from Customers
join orders on Customers.serial = orders.customerid
join order_detail on orders.serial = order_detail.orderid
```

You can also create another table called `Product` and join the same way as i have showed you.

If you want to select columns from different tables then you have to do like using `tablename.columnname`. So for example if you want to select quantity and price from order_detail table then do following

```
 Select * from Customers,order_detail.quantity,order_detail.price
join orders on Customers.serial = orders.customerid
join order_detail on orders.serial = order_detail.orderid
```

Hope you got my point.

Comment: How will i call them if they are joined like that? :)

Comment: @user3361094 cant you see that i am selecting customers data? what do you mean call them?

Comment: by using `Table.ColumnName`